# Is there a way to replace salesforce logo in OAuth Login Webview for Android?

Tags: android, oauth, salesforce, android-webview, oauth-2.0

Is there a way to replace salesforce logo in OAuth Login Webview for Android with organization specific logo? I tried to do it using "Logo Image URL" field in Remote Access, but its not replacing the salesforce logo. Is there any other way?

For screenshot, please visit the link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF0Pp.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the oAuth window, you cannot change the logo here due to oAuth restrictions. This is because your organisation is not authenticating the user, Salesforce is, and they are required to show their logo here.

Hope that makes sense!

Anup

Comment: You are right sir. But what I actually mean is, at the first glance there is no way to inform our customer that they are using the android app made by our company. So either salesforce should provide a method to show our company logo or their should be some way to replace or override the current outh2 webview.

By the way, thanks for your reply.

Comment: If your goal is to let the user know that this is your company app, then you should have a splash screen with your company logo before the actual oAuth authentication screen. That is when the user opens the app, he will see the landing page with your company logo, with a button or a link to "login using oAuth".

Comment: Yes this is one alternative. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Almost same concern here, but is there a way to put a default values in the input? and changing the actionbar in that area. thanks